# Cumulative integral of the Marchenko-Pastur density for Wishart eigenvalues

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, integration, specific-calculation

I can't find any work on the cumulative density function of the well-known Marchenko-Pastur density for the eigenvalues of a standard Wishart Matrix as its dimension goes to $\infty$, i.e. 
$$F(\beta)=\int_{a}^{\beta}\frac{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}{2\pi x \rho }dx$$
where the density exists on the interval $(a,b)$, in which $a=(1-\sqrt{\rho})^{2}$, $b=(1+\sqrt{\rho})^{2}$, and $0<\rho <1$. I can find the moments of the density. They do have simple forms.

Answer (score 5):

The following explicit formulas, with $R=(x-a)(b-x)$, allow one to estimate the cumulative density function:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{R}}{x}dx=\sqrt{R}+\frac{a+b}{2}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{R}}-ab\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R}},$$
together with 
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{R}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{2x-a-b}{b-a}\right),$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\arcsin\left(\frac{(a+b)x-2ab}{x(b-a)}\right),$$
see respectively formulas 2.261 and 2.266 of I.S. Gradshteyn, I.M. Ryzhik, Table of integrals, series, and products.

For instance, for $\rho=1/4$, the density and cumulative function look like:
[image]

Comment: To complete the answer: If you call F(x) the integral computed above, then CDF(x) = F(x) - F(a). Actually if you do the calculation, F(a) = - 0.5.